# SQLITE - Open two connections (read and write) at once

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a C# program that needs to read record by record from a DB, then it makes some operations on two columns and then writes on a new column.
So far I did like this:

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn_write = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path + ";PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;"))
{
    conn_write.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd_write = new SQLiteCommand(conn_write);

    using (SQLiteConnection conn_read = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path + ";PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;"))
    {
        conn_read.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd_read = new SQLiteCommand(conn_read);
        SQLiteDataReader reader;

        sql_read = "SELECT ID, ETRF2000_FI, ETRF2000_LA FROM Tutto_NonAbolito";
        cmd_read.CommandText = sql_read;
        reader = cmd_read.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            MobileKat.ALCoord.ETRF200ToLL84(reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("ETRF2000_FI")), reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("ETRF2000_LA")), ref lon, ref lat);
            sql_write = "UPDATE Tutto_NonAbolito SET LL84_LON = " + lon + ", LL84_LAT = " + lat + " WHERE " + reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID")) + " = ID;";
            cmd_write.CommandText = sql_write;
            cmd_write.ExecuteReader();
        }

        conn_read.Close();
    }

    conn_write.Close();
}
```

I also tried to add PRAGMA but it still tells me that the database file is locked.. Is there a way to do that in this way? I wouldn't like to save the columns in an array and then open another connection. I prefer to do it "on-the-run" if it is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need two connections?

Comment: because I need to read the first reader line by line and then make some calculations on two columns of the current record and then make an update of the database and write on another column..

Comment: This does not answer my question. Why couldn't you do this with a single connection?